# Microsoft Outlook Mail Merge single email delay

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there any way to have outlook send one email every x amount of minutes from a mail merged list?

I don't want to just delay the whole set. I want it to send one email, wait a given amount of time, send another email, wait, send, wait ... etc